# Remove border from object element in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I can't remove inset borders from object elements in IE11. They don't appear in any other browser or version of IE as far as I can tell. See the attached screenshot. Setting border as an attribute or inline style doesn't work... any ideas?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you used developer tools for inspecting these elements and trying to removing borders?

Comment: Could you please make a jsfiddle which reproduces your problem?

Comment: @phts hrrmm... I tried but haven't been able to reproduce it — but you can see the bug in action [here](http://192.241.199.239:8082/i/mJVfePWi?preview)

Comment: And yes, I did use the developer tools to try to remove the borders to no avail.

Comment: Seems IE11 tries to load object content and fails and renders an empty content with borders. So it has nothing to do with `<object>` element's border, it's content. There are some errors appear `WebSocket Error: Incorrect HTTP response. Status code 403, Forbidden` may be related to this. Try to load existing content to `object`s.

Comment: Did you finid a solution to this? I am currently experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add border-style: none; to your css for that div.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with object images which were loading over script. The object data attribute wasn't defined so it was putting this border around the object. Adding a 1x1px blank image as the data attribute made it happy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

border-width:none
or
-webkit-border-before: unset;

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.