# IE11 adds beveled borders to object with ng-attr-data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a problem with objects, caused by using Angular.js to populate the data url of the object with `ng-attr-data`. My objects are svgs (necessary for animation, and have worked fine in IE until changing to angular.js).

Internet Explorer is rendering the content with a bevelled box like an iFrame because it doesn't find a data attribute initially on document load, and only when angular changes/adds the attribute. If the data url is hardcoded, it works fine and doesn't put the border around it.

I've tried setting `border-style`, `border-width`, `outline`, `frameborder` attribute, `border` attribute - but nothing works.

I attempted to use `ng-if` on the object tags to prevent them from rendering, but it still behaves the same (I assume because it's in the document and not actually excluded from processing).

This is the offending element markup:

```
<object ng-attr-data="{{url}}" id="svgobject" type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
```

A Plunk demonstrating the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/3vom2L8IRNEskSnKIrfm?p=preview

This is potentially a related issue:
[Remove border from object element in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478728/remove-border-from-object-element-in-ie11)

Comment: can you create plunk which reproduce this?

Comment: I'm hoping this will work - it renders in firefox, but unfortunately in IE it's not even populating the second svg that is set by angular.
http://plnkr.co/edit/qyOSZM?p=preview

Comment: After attempting it in a plunk, it doesn't appear to exhibit the same behaviour, although the content for the injected url's svg doesn't render.
UPDATE: after adding the type="image/svg+xml" which I had in my original code, it now replicates the behaviour in plunker. Without the type, the injected svg doesn't render at all after initial page load.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem by creating an angular directive to inject the object into the page - thereby removing the case where an object exists with no data="" attribute being set at page load. The directive replaces the div that it is set on with an object tag and passes in the data-svgname attribute as the new object's name and id attributes.

If chrome doesn't have names specified in SVGs there are odd cases when its caching algorithm messes up and randomly replaces SVGs on the page with others already cached.

```
myApp.directive('injectSvg', function ($compile) {
        //Usage: 
        // <div inject-svg data-url="{{'svgfile.svg'}}" data-svgname="mysvg" class="svg"></div>
        //Replaces with SVG graphic
        return {
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                var el = angular.element('<object data="' + $attrs.url + '" id="' + $attrs.svgname + '" name="' + $attrs.svgname + '" type="image/svg+xml" class="' + $attrs.class + '"></object>');
                $compile(el)($scope);
                $element.replaceWith(el);


            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into the same problem. I'm not sure if it's a 100% valid way to deal with it, but so far I can't see any errors or whatsoever (checked in Chrome, FF, Safari, IE, Edge). Basically just added an empty "data" attribute:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="" ng-attr-data="{{url}}" id="svgobject"></object>
```

The downside is that you have to set the size of the element, otherwise there's some weird jumping going on

Comment: Works but its not usable because some browsers trying to load the current page inside.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand exactly, but if you want remove border any html element ? you have two choice :
1-)You can use border-style, border-width, outline attributes or
2-)You can use css add a class on your html element like following code

```
<div ng-app="" class="borderless">
  Some content...
</div>
```

and add your stylesheet file following code

```
.borderless{
  Border:none;
  /*or border:0;*/
  outline:none;

}
```

Comment: This isn't a border that can be modified via css (as mentioned in the question). No styling seems to affect it, which is why it's such a frustrating issue.

Comment: can i see your a code part ? with with ng-attr-data i am look in explorer